# Accidentally deleted the only partition where LV for the root and swap

Tags: linux, lvm, fdisk

I accidentally deleted `/dev/sda2`. This is only partition which is member of my `rhel` VG. where I have created `root` and `swap` LV. I deleted this with `fdisk`, after deleting I run `partprobe` It gave some error then I reboot VM. Now it's stuck on `a start job is running for /dev_mapper_rhel/x2droot.device`.

Is there any way to recreate that partition? Can I make changes after mounting this disk to a Live Os?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can recreate the partition using `fdisk`, or another other similar tool. All you need to do is input the start and end offsets as they used to be.

And yes, you can make changes from a live disc.